# How i can convert string to list

Tags: python

I have string:

```
[('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'IN'),('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]
```

I want get list

```
[['We', 'PRP'], ['are', 'VBP'], ['going', 'VBG'], ['out.Just', 'IN'],['you', 'PRP'], ['and', 'CC'], ['me', 'PRP'], ['.', '.']
```

How i can do it?

Comment: What you have is an array of tuples ,not a string

Comment: You have a tuple that you want to convert to a list

Comment: `myList = [list(a) for a in myList]`

Comment: @NickA: you've been around long enough to know the difference between a comment and an answer.

Comment: @DSM Yes, but I also wouldn't have made the effort to post it as more of a codedump on this quality of question, I also would expect better quality answers to come considering I was on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple list comprehension: Iterate through the whole list.

```
  x = [('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'IN'),('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]
  new = [list(i) for i in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Map list over the values:

```
the_list = [('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'IN'),('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]

new_list = map(list, the_list)
```

Edit:

Another method that does not create an iterator is list comprehension:

```
new_list = [list(i) for i in the_list]
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `map` function doesn't produce a `list` but a `iterator`?

Comment: That is correct. In that case, list comprehension or a for loop can create a list

Comment: map returns a **list** in case of `python2.x` and **iterator** in the case of `python3.x` . Since OP did not mention the python version

Comment: People are saying that the difference between 2 and 3 is minimal, but it is actually pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` with `lambda` that iterate over each element in the original list (with is a tuple) and convert it to a list. This way you get a list of lists:

```
org_list = [('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'IN'),('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]

output_list = map(lambda l: list(l), lst)
```